# How to use leaflet.bezier plugin in react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to use a leaflet plugin called leaflet-geotiff (https://github.com/lifeeka/leaflet.bezier) but I'm using leaflet react. Is it possible for me to convert this plugin to a leaflet-react version?

Comment: You mention `leaflet-geotiff` but then you include `leaflet-bezier` library url. Which of the 2 you want to use?

Comment: Sorry i want to use the Leaflet.bezier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install & import `leaflet.bezier` & `snapsvg` which is a dependency of the first:

```
import "snapsvg";
import "leaflet.bezier";
```

Create a custom react-leaflet component using native leaflet code, place it where the component mounts. Use also the imported plane image to reproduce the example demo:

```
function LeafletBezier() {
  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  useEffect(() => {
    const dash_straight = {
      color: "rgb(145, 146, 150)",
      fillColor: "rgb(145, 146, 150)",
      dashArray: 8,
      opacity: 0.8,
      weight: "1",
      iconTravelLength: 1,
      iconMaxWidth: 50,
      iconMaxHeight: 50,
      fullAnimatedTime: 7000,
      easeOutPiece: 4,
      easeOutTime: 2500
    };

    L.bezier(
      {
        path: [
          [
            { lat: 7.8731, lng: 80.7718, slide: "RIGHT_ROUND" }, //Sri Lanka
            { lat: -25.2744, lng: 133.7751, slide: "LEFT_ROUND" }, //Australia
            { lat: 36.2048, lng: 138.2529 } //Japan
          ],
          [
            { lat: 7.8731, lng: 80.7718, slide: "RIGHT_ROUND" }, //Sri Lanka
            { lat: 3.139, lng: 101.6869 }
          ],
          [
            { lat: 7.8731, lng: 80.7718, slide: "RIGHT_ROUND", deep: "8" }, //Sri Lanka
            { lat: 41.8719, lng: 12.5674 }
          ],
          [
            { lat: -25.2744, lng: 133.7751 }, //Australia
            { lat: -40.9006, lng: 174.886 } //Japan
          ],
          [
            { lat: 7.8731, lng: 80.7718, slide: "RIGHT_ROUND" },
            { lat: -18.7669, lng: 46.8691 }
          ]
        ],
        icon: {
          path: plane
        }
      },
      dash_straight
    ).addTo(map);
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

Use it inside react-leaflet's `<Map />`:

```
<Map ...> 
  <LeafletBezier />
</Map>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-leafletbezier-plugin-in-react-leaflet-g2m0s?file=/src/Leaflet.jsx:497-514)

**Edit**

Using `snapsvg` library since a while gives an error

> eve is not defined

so use snapsvg-cjs libray instead `npm i snapsvg-cjs`

and import it using

```
import Snap from "snapsvg-cjs";
```

Comment: Yes it worked thank u bro. what is the use of SnapSVG in this code.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are new to SO.

Comment: SnapSVG is used for vector graphics, the plane animation in the particular case

Comment: instead of importing `Snap`, `import "snapsvg-cjs";`